# Flutter - PlatformException when using an ACTION_EDIT intent

Tags: android, android-intent, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the `android_intent` package for sending the `ACTION_EDIT` intent in order to make an image editable but I keep getting an error.

I have looked up the issue online and saw that I need to create a class that extends `FileProvider` if my `SDK` version is higher than or equal to `24` in order to solve the problem but I couldn't figure out how to do that in flutter.

The function I am using in order to pick the image and send it to the phone editor:

```
Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var intent =
          AndroidIntent(action: 'action_edit', data: image.uri.toString());
      await intent.launch();
    }

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/eebbf5f6-0a08-462b-9564-63c1a226e6a24636306815702344465.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData(), null))

I/io.flutter.plugins.androidintent.AndroidIntentPlugin(30575): Sending intent Intent { act=action_edit dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/eebbf5f6-0a08-462b-9564-63c1a226e6a24636306815702344465.jpg }
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575): android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/eebbf5f6-0a08-462b-9564-63c1a226e6a24636306815702344465.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10936)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10887)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1667)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4688)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4646)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(30575):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5007)
```

Do you know how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of solved the problem, I changed the package of intents from `android_intent` to `intent` and then I somehow got to see the available apps for `ACTION_EDIT` which there are not on my emulator/phone.

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be solved with android_intent package.

I somehow encountered this problem and after searching and trying, I solved it like this:

Instead of "action_edit", I have used "android.intent.action.EDIT" as the "action".

```
var intent = AndroidIntent(
                 action: 'android.intent.action.EDIT', 
                 data: image.uri.toString(),
             );
```